# QEMU SPARC VM - SCP to localhost

Tags: virtual-machine, scp, qemu, sparc

I have to use QEMU VM to emulate SPARC. I've been trying to SCP my finished assignment to my localhost, but I seem to be unable to. Whenever I try:

```
scp assignment6.zip user@ipv4address:~/
```

I get this error:
ssh: connect to host ipv4address port 22: Connection refused

I've opened up port 22, and still continue to get this error.

I assume there's something simple I'm missing, but I can really see what it is.

If there are any suggestions, I'd be grateful to hear them.

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to have the port "open" in the firewall. The "connection refused" message usually means that there is no process listening on the port. I'd recommend checking to see if you actually have an ssh server running on the localhost.